# Conditionally setting style depending on router url

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I have this global script in Angular 10 that evaluates the current path and sets a style to the navigation bar conditionally. However since I'm using router links for some reason if fails sometimes. I wanted to know if there was an Angular/Typescript way of doing this, or just a better way that will work with router links.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (window.location.pathname != "/") {
    $('#main-nav').css('background-color', 'black');
  }
});
```

Basically what it does is: if the page is not the homepage, make the navbar black.

I saw something about using ngOnInitView but I'm not sure where to put it(should it be in my navbar component?)

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you have the conditional in your markup?   you could conditionally had a css class to your html object.   `[ngClass]="{ myClass: conditional, myOtherClass: otherconditional}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilise the Angular Router service (`@angular/router`) from your navbar component to watch for router changes.

```
isHome: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.events
    .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))  
    .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.isHome = event.url === "/"; // Toggle a boolean based on url
    });
}
```

And in your navbar html, one of many options is to use ngClass or ngStyle to update the styling of your bar. For instance;

```
<div id="main-nav" [style.background-color]="isHome ? 'black' : null">
    Main
</div>
```

Comment: why in angular 12 the filter function gives this *Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event_2, unknown>'* error?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can do something like this to get the route

Using `Router` from `@angular/router`

In the constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
```

Then you can get the url route using

```
this.router.url
```

Also if you need to "listen" for changes subscribe to it using

```
this.router.events.subscribe((value) => {
  If (val instance of NavigationEnd){
    this.onRoute = val.url;
  }
}
```

Note: the `this.onRoute` is a declared variable `public onRoute: string`

Then you can use the `onRoute` variable to check anything for the route.

Also in the Html you can use something like this to add the `noHomeBackground` class (this is your custom class for all the style you want to apply) when the condition `this.onRoute!=='/'` matches.

```
<div [class.noHomeBackgroud]="this.onRoute!=='/'">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, to manipulate the style property of any HTML DOM depending on the route it is navigating, we can do the following:

in the *div.component.html*

```
<div [ngClass]="[router.isActive('/colored-div', true) ? 'colored-div': 'non-colored-div' ]">
```

Using **[ngClass]** inside the HTML element, we are doing a conditional rendering of CSS classes on the basis of whether the route is active or not.

**isActive()** function is determining if the mentioned URL is activated or not.

in the *div.component.css*

```
div {
   width:90%;
   height:10vh;
}
.colored-div {
   background-color: skyblue;
}

.non-colored-div {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

inside the constructor of *div.component.ts*

```
constructor(public router: Router){}
```

Notice that the router has to be **public** to give its access to the template.